# Xml searching node issue

Tags: c#, xml

I have a following XML structure :

```
<html xmlns ="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head>
  . .
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I used linq to xml to access div with id = "2". I loaded document in XDocument :

```
   XDocument  ndoc = XDcoument.load(path);
   XElement n = new XElement("name","value");
   XNamespace xn = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

ndoc.Descendants(xn + "div").Single(p => p.Attribute("id").Value == "1").Add(n);

                             OR

ndoc.Descendants("div").Single(p => p.Attribute("id").Value == "1").Add(n);
```

I tried out both case in each case there was an exception sequence contain no element. Whats the problem here?

Comment: You say you are looking for `div with id = "2"` but in your code you are checking for `...Value == "1"`  So which do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this [Xml Library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/) a whirl and it should get it easily with:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(path);
XElement div = root.XPathElement("//div[@id={0}]", 1);
if(null != div) // which it shouldn't be
    div.Add(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
XNamespace xn = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
ndoc.Descendants(xn + "div").Single(p => p.Attribute("id").Value == "1").Add(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
XDocument ndoc =XDcoument.load(path);
XElement n = new XElement("name", "value");
XNamespace xn = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

var item = ndoc.Descendants(xn + "div").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Attribute("id").Value == "1");
if(item!=null)
    item.Add(n);
```

Use `Single` method, if you are Sure that There will be only one element coming out of your expression. If by any chance, there may be more than one element coming , use `FirstOrDefault`()

Keep in mind that `Descendants()` will give you all the elements with the matching condition from any Sub level ( Children, Grand Children etc...)

`Elements()` method will give you only the Immediate (Direct) Child.

So use it carefully.

Comment: Don't you think that the real problem is not exception, but not finding the searched element? Exception is only the result =)

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy: Yes.  that is why i am doing a null checking before calling the Add method. having the namespace inside the Descendants method will get you the element if it exist.

Answer (score 0):

For me your example (a bit modified) works fine:

```
 var xml = @"<html xmlns ='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' >
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='1'></div>
  <div id='2'></div>
 </body>
</html>";
            XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement n = new XElement("name", "value");
            XNamespace xn = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

            xd.Descendants(xn + "div").Single(p => p.Attribute("id").Value == "1").Add(n);

            Console.WriteLine(xd);
```

outputs

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="1">
      <name xmlns="">value</name>
    </div>
    <div id="2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I don't really understand your problem. Please check if you copied all correct =)